# Returning a result from an asynchronous function call

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

```
 async function checkStreamStatus(channelName) {
  const response = await  fetch(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_login=${channelName}`,  {

    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + '',
      'Client-Id': '',
      
    }});

  const json = await response.json();
  const type = json.data[0]?.type;
  
  status = type;
  //console.log("worked " + status)
  
  if (status === "live") {
    return true;
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
  
  
 }
```

My brain couldn't handle how async function works even i watched 3 videos and spent 3 hours how can i return true and false from this function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIkXu.png)

Comment: I read nearly all of these but i can't understand if someone can convert my example to working one i hope i can learn

Comment: You `await` the function call.

Comment: If its async it means you can only a promise, in this case you return a promise that the value in its .then function would be a boolean. Whats the problem?

Comment: what a website people can choose my problem is solved, really i know understand why people only uses this website at reading only mode

Comment: your code is correct, the issue is probably with the way you call `checkStreamStatus()`. Could you add the example of how you call your `checkStreamStatus` function?

Comment: Krivi, there are tons of questions answered about JS promises. An async question returns a promise, so you can't directly return a boolean value. You need to "thenize" the call of an async function in order to get its return value, since when an async function returns something it means the promise it returns is in fulfilled/rejected state. If you are confused about promises try to get the basics of the argument by reading some documentation.